# Why is the channel affected by mutex?

Tags: go, mutex

I don't know why `c <- i` is working when mutex is used.

Because there is `rwMutex.Lock()` in the first line of the `second()` function.

If `mutex` is not working in a channel, the following output values are not understood.
output values come in order from 1.

1. execute `go second(...)`
2. execute `rwMutex.Lock()`
3. so `c <- i` not be run because write is locked!
4. but `num := <-c` is working.

**main.go**

```golang
var (
    dataSendChannel = make(chan int)
    rwMutex         = new(sync.RWMutex)
)

func main() {
    go first(dataSendChannel)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 100)
}

func first(c chan<- int) {
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        go second(dataSendChannel)
        c <- i
    }
}

func second(c <-chan int) {
    rwMutex.Lock()
    num := <-c
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(10-num) * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("[NUM] : ", num)
    rwMutex.Unlock()
}
```

**output**

```
[NUM] :  1
[NUM] :  2
[NUM] :  3
[NUM] :  4
[NUM] :  5
[NUM] :  6
[NUM] :  7
[NUM] :  8
[NUM] :  9
[NUM] :  10
```

---

This is the output value when not used `mutex` .

**main.go**

```golang
func second(c <-chan int) {
    num := <-c
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(10-num) * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("[NUM] : ", num)
}
```

**output**

```
[NUM] :  10
[NUM] :  9
[NUM] :  8
[NUM] :  7
[NUM] :  6
[NUM] :  5
[NUM] :  4
[NUM] :  3
[NUM] :  2
[NUM] :  1
```

Does mutex work after receiving one data on the channel?

Comment: Your output is what I would expect to see; by adding a Mutex you are preventing concurrent execution. Perhaps it would help if you add details of what you expect to happen and why.

Comment: @Brits I add some expect happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you lock variable `num` with the mutex, you are preventing the subsequent goroutines to lock the mutex, because it is not yet unlocked.

Therefore, the second goroutine really waits till the first finishes sleeping (for 9 seconds) and then prints the number 1. Only at that very moment the second goroutine can lock the mutex and write to variable `num`, but the third can't access yet, so it waits again, till the second goroutine prints the number and so on.

Without mutex, the first goroutine sleeps the longest time and it doesn't prevent others from execution and writing to `num`, so it prints the lastest, others can do their work first, because the sleep less time and finish faster.

If you delete sleeping, it will work the same in both cases.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var (
    dataSendChannel = make(chan int)
    rwMutex         = new(sync.RWMutex)
)

func main() {
    go first(dataSendChannel)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 100)
}

func first(c chan<- int) {
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        go second(dataSendChannel)
        c <- i
    }
}

func second(c <-chan int) {
    rwMutex.Lock()
    num := <-c
    fmt.Println("[NUM] : ", num)
    rwMutex.Unlock()
}
```

Comment: `num` is local variable, why don't use `num` in another goroutine?

Comment: I thought mutex locks the variables  in `lock` and `unlock` , but now I realize that the same goroutines doesn't work until mutex is unlocked.

Comment: yes, exactly. When mutex is not yet unlocked, you can not lock it again, so the goroutine needs to wait.

Comment: The example in the [tour](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/9) may help if you are still unsure.